# wait for the end of another job before starting one

Tags: hudson

I have two jobs on Hudson, A & B.

I just want to put B in queue if a build of A is already on-going.
Actually I would like to set A as upstream project of B but without setting A as downstream project (plus "Block build when upstream project is building" advanced option), because I don't need to build B each time A is triggered.

As B build step is a python script, I know I can poll

```
http://myhudson/srs/job/A/api/json?tree=builds[building]
```

periodically and wait for a `true` value in top `building` result, but during this polling, B will be "in progress", and it would be clearer to just have B in queue.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use the [Exclusion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin) and set up the two jobs to be mutually exclusive.